# Split list by two things at once python

Tags: python, html, pandas, web-scraping, split

I am defining a function that scrapes HTML, puts the output into a list, and separates the data by `", "`. However, I want to split this list by both `"\n"` and `", "`. So far I am only able to do one or the other but not simultaneously. Here is my code.

```
#libraries
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen
import requests

#function
def scrape_html(url):
    body = []
    reqs = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(urlopen(url).read())

    for tag in soup.find_all('body'):
        new_line=soup.get_text('\n')
        body.append(new_line)
    
    comma_split=[i.split(', ') for i in body]
    return comma_split
```

The output separates by comma but the `"\n"` remains.

```
#output
[['{"Last Name": "SMITH"',
  '"First Name": "JOHN"',
  '"Annual Salary": "100,000.00"}\nRequest: John Smith\n{"Last Name": "WYLIE"',
  '"First Name": "SAM"', ...]]
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to SO! Are you dealing with JSON here? What URL is being fetched or what does the markup look like?

Comment: @ggorlen thanks! yup JSON object. Here is an example of the URL: https://www.uchicago.computer/api.php?file=ee5da62087f0dff1034155ff49ab91157bf1a9effe78bb952a3e9ecb0a275fd4

Comment: OK, why not use `json.loads(string)` instead of trying to roll your own parser?

Comment: @ggorlen good point! not too familiar with JSON library yet so I decided to stick with what I (kind of) know. The end goal is to split the list's separated values into their own rows in a pandas DataFrame.

Comment: I see the API isn't returning JSON. You might want to look into the API to see if you can get a usable response. Just keep in mind that if one of the strings has a newline or comma, the solution you've accepted breaks. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `re.split` for a more powerful splitting mechanism:

```py
#libraries
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen
import requests
import re

#function
def scrape_html(url):
    body = []
    reqs = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(urlopen(url).read())

    for tag in soup.find_all('body'):
        new_line=soup.get_text('\n')
        body.append(new_line)
    
    comma_split=[re.split('(?:\n|, )', i) for i in body]
    return comma_split
```

Here, the `(?:)` just means non-capturing, and the `\n|,`  matches with either a newline or a comma followed by a string.

Comment: @ggorlen, just answering the original question

Comment: JSON also only works with a single object per string: `json.loads('{"a":"b"}\n{"a":"b"}')` would fail to work

Comment: Yeah it turns out OP isn't working with JSON but there has to be a better solution than regex. [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), I say...

Comment: @ggorlen I agree. I think splitting by a regex pattern of the sort `\nRequest sent:` might work a lot better.

Comment: Yeah, but that depends on the nature of the API. Who knows if that can be relied upon so OP has more explanation/research to provide. Thanks for helping anyway, hopefully this gets them rolling.

Comment: @ggorlen of course. Until we get further information, we can't say anything for sure